# Compare TypeOf "List<int>" to "System.Collections.Generic.List<int>"

Tags: c#, reflection, roslyn

I am building a code refactoring tool in which I get two variable types using tokens/nodes from the Roslyn API.

I need to compare and validate whether the two types are the same. 
Some other questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3788225/generic-class-type-gettype) which work in case you have objects, however I need to work with strings and compare types in this case.Heres my method which works with `typeName = "int"`, however when `typeName="List<int>"` I get `null`

```
 public static Type GetType(string typeName)
    {
        string clrType = null;

        if (CLRConstants.TryGetValue(typeName, out clrType))
        {
            return Type.GetType(clrType);
        }


        var type = Type.GetType(typeName);

        if (type != null) return type;
        foreach (var a in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
        {
            type = a.GetType(typeName);
            if (type != null)
                return type;
        }
        return null;
    }
    private static Dictionary<string, string> CLRConstants { get{
            var dct =  new Dictionary<string, string>();
            dct.Add("int", "System.Int32");
            return dct;

        } }
```

Comment: Is something about this code not working? Can you perhaps [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53941314/edit) that information into your question?

Comment: if typeName is "List<int>" I am getting null

Comment: Do you mean that you want to first realise that `List<...>` is generic, and look that up, and then lookup `int` and construct `List<int>`? Or what?

Comment: This i totally irrelevant to the question, However... you set of my OCD, `a` is a terrible name for anything

Comment: @TheGeneral standard way to shorten result of `GetAssemblies` call to 3 letters looks unprofessional... so `a` in *this case* is ok :)

Comment: @John yes, so that I can compare whether type of "List<int>" and "System.Collections.Generic.List<int>" are equal

Comment: I imagine you would have to start with the innermost generic parameters and work outwards, resolving as you go.

Comment: I was going to write an answer to this, though it wasn't really a solve.. but you will have to definitely check for namespaces, and make sure any type you find in an assembly actually represents a type that might be in your parsed code. I mean this is going to fail all over the place if you don't compare types against the namespaces that might be in scope

Answer (score 0):

You can get and check all possible assembly types by the below code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            foreach (var a in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
            {
                foreach (var b in a.GetTypes())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(b.FullName);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the printed list there is

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1
```

which is for

```
List<T>
```

types.
If you want your exact need which is

```
List<int>
```

You have to write

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]
```

So your code will work like this:

```
public static Type GetType(string typeName)
{
    string clrType = null;

    if (CLRConstants.TryGetValue(typeName, out clrType))
    {
        return Type.GetType(clrType);
    }

    var type = Type.GetType(typeName);

    if (type != null) return type;
    foreach (var a in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
    {
        type = a.GetType(typeName);
        if (type != null)
            return type;
    }
    return null;
}
private static Dictionary<string, string> CLRConstants { 
    get{
            var dct =  new Dictionary<string, string>();
            dct.Add("int", "System.Int32");
            dct.Add("List<int>", "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]");
            return dct;
    } 
}
```